# Using BETWEEN with Dates SQL and Coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to grab orders between certain dates using the `BETWEEN` operator in SQL.

My date formats are in dd/mm/yyyy format.

ord_fdate is the from date: Currently 01/03/2012
ord_tdate is the to date: Currently 07/03/2012

I thought this would return all orders from 01/03/2012  (including 01/03/2012) to 07/03/2012 (including 07/03/2012).

However, it does not get orders with dates 07/03/2012

My query below; i have also included the debug output of the query;

```
<cfset ord_fdate = DateFormat(ord_fdate, "dd/mm/yyyy")>
<cfset ord_tdate = DateFormat(ord_tdate, "dd/mm/yyyy")>
<cfquery name="getOrders" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT 
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders,
  dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp

FROM
  dbo.tbl_orders
  WHERE dbo.tbl_orders.uid_order_webid=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.webid#">
  AND bit_order_archive=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="no">
  AND txt_order_status=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="Awaiting Dispatch">
  AND dte_order_stamp BETWEEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#createODBCDate(ord_fdate)#"> AND <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#createODBCDate(ord_tdate)#">
  ORDER BY dte_order_stamp DESC
</cfquery>
```

Debug;

```
WHERE (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_order_webid=?
  AND bit_order_archive=?
  AND txt_order_status=?
  AND dte_order_stamp BETWEEN ? AND ?)


  ORDER BY dte_order_stamp DESC
Query Parameter Value(s) -
Parameter #1(cf_sql_integer) = 1
Parameter #2(cf_sql_bit) = NO
Parameter #3(cf_sql_varchar) = Awaiting Dispatch
Parameter #4(cf_sql_date) = {ts '2012-03-01 00:00:00'}
Parameter #5(cf_sql_date) = {ts '2012-03-07 00:00:00'}
```

Not sure why it is not working.

Database is SQL 2008

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the date has a time component? If the end date has a time component, say 07/03/2012 03:00:12, then it will not match. Also, you have a typo in your code: "<cfset ord_tdate = DateFormat(ord_tdate, "dd/dd/yyyy")>"

Comment: @Jason - Are you sure DateFormat(.., "dd/mm/yyyy")> is really doing what you think it is? DateFormat (and createODBCDate) always assume the *input* is in U.S. date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your date field include time?  If so, between will only give you values >= the first date, and <= the second date at midnight. Any date that includes a time past midnight will be ignored.

I usually do something like this when dealing with dates:

If I want everything from 1/1/2012 I set up the start date as 1/1/2012, and the end date as one day later (at midnight)...

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '01/01/2012'
declare @EndDate datetime = '01/02/2012'
```

Then select the values like this:

```
select * from your_table where date >= @StartDate and date < @EndDate
```

When checking against the end date I want anything with a value less than the end date. This will include values such as 1/1/2012 12:30, 1/1/2012 23:20, etc.

Comment: Hi this has worked, i added an extra day to the to date and it is now returning the correct results 


`<cfset ord_tdate = DateFormat(arguments.ord_tdate, "dd/mm/yyyy")>
<cfset ord_tdate = DateAdd('d', 1, ord_tdate)>`

Comment: Make sure you don't use `BETWEEN` when doing it this way, because that is inclusive and will give you dates that match the end date at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND (DATE(dte_order_stamp) >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#createODBCDate(ord_fdate)#">),
AND (DATE(dte_order_stamp) <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#createODBCDate(ord_tdate)#">)
```

Comment: Though the net effect is the same as using `>= .. and .. <` keep in mind using functions on a column may sometimes prevent the use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which database you're using and you didn't specify which one you are, but many do not treat `BETWEEN` as being inclusive.

I usually just use `>=` and `<=` with two clauses. It may or may not be less efficient, but I know specifically what I'm testing against.

Comment: Re: *but many do not treat `BETWEEN` as being inclusive* Just curious, which databases? IIRC the standards define BETWEEN as inclusive, recent ones anyway.

Comment: I don't remember off hand as I have only read posts about it or heard about it from other developers.

Comment: Weird. None of those I have used (sybase, mySQL, ms sql, oracle, ..) were exclusive. Maybe they were thinking of an older db or a different operator? If you do come across a reference post it. I would be curious to know which db's buck the standards ;)